# Google Web Master Tools won't Index my Ghost Blog

Tags: google-search-console, ghost

Few days ago, i've submited the sitemap to Google Web Master Tools, but no one single page was indexed.

Here's my sitemap: [ghost.asepmaulanaismail.com/sitemap.xml](http://ghost.asepmaulanaismail.com/sitemap.xml)

Sitemap Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx0TC.png

my robot.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://ghost.asepmaulanaismail.com/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /ghost/
```

am i missing something?